# Python generates an IO error while interleaving open/close/readline/write on the same file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python-this gives me an IO error-

```
f = open('money.txt')
while True:
    currentmoney = float(f.readline())
    print(currentmoney, end='')
    if currentmoney >= 0:
        howmuch = (float(input('How much did you put in or take out?:')))

        now = currentmoney + howmuch
        print(now)
        str(now)
        f.close()
    f = open('money.txt', 'w')
    f.write(str(now))
    f.close()
```

Thanks!

Comment: at what line the error is ....add the error message that is sown in interpreter

Comment: Should this kind of question be encouraged on Stack Overflow? This is not the kind of question that someone with the same problem will be able to find. If a large number of people asked this kind of questions, we would end up with tons of "What's wrong with this code?" questions. Does SO have a policy about this?

Comment: @Virgil: This kind of question is perfectly fine. We _do_ get tons of what's wrong with this code questions. It's part of the site.

Comment: There are lots of questions like this, but it would still be nice if it had a better title... I'll fix that.

Comment: By the way, this look like Python 3?  If so, you may wish to add the "python3.0" tag.

Comment: @virgil I think it's a perfectly fine question. SO isn't just a resource for General Solve X problems. People should be able to rely on the community to get help with specific problems.

Comment: The presence of code is a BIG step up from folks who ask "plzsendtehcodez" questions where they're asking for code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `while True` is going to loop forever unless you break it with `break`.

The I/O error is probably because when you have run through the loop once the last thing you do is `f.close()`, which closes the file. When execution continues with the loop in the line `currentmoney = float(f.readline())`: `f` will be a closed filehandle that you can't read from.

Answer (score 2):

well theres a couple of things...

you `open(money.txt)` outside the while loop but you close it after the first iteration...
(technically you close, reopen & close again)

Put when the loop comes round the second time, `f` will be closed and f.readLine() will most likely fail

Answer (score 0):

You close your file only if the IF condition is satisfied, otherwise you attempt to reopen it after the IF block. Depending on the result you want to achieve you will want to either remove the f.close call, or add an ELSE branch and remove the second f.open call. Anyway let me warn you that the str(now) in your IF block is just deprecated as you're not saving the result of that call anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get an IO Error on your first line if money.txt doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Can I piggyback a question?  The following has puzzled me for some time.  I always get an IOError from these 'open()' statements, so I've stopped checking for the error.  (Don't like to do that!)  What's wrong with my code?  The 'if IOError:' test shown in comments was originally right after the statement with 'open()'.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
#get name of input file and open() infobj
    infname = sys.argv[1]
    print 'infname is:  %s' % (sys.argv[1])
    infobj = open( infname, 'rU' )
    print 'infobj is:  %s' % infobj
# 'if IOError:' always evals to True!?!
#   if IOError:
#       print 'IOError opening file tmp with mode rU.'
#       sys.exit( 1)

#get name of output file and open() outfobj
    outfname = sys.argv[2]
    print 'outfname is: %s' % (sys.argv[2])
    outfobj = open( outfname, 'w' )
    print 'outfobj is: %s' % outfobj
#   if IOError:
#       print 'IOError opening file otmp with mode w.'
#       sys.exit( 2)
```

Comment: IOError is an exception. You don't check for exceptions with 'if', you do it with try.... except IOError. IOError itself, like any value except for 0, False and an empty list, evaluates to True.

Comment: You know, I said to myself as I was typing that, "I wonder if I've ever tried 'try ... except ...' there.  THANK YOU for a clear, precise, full, and accurate answer.  Not to mention nearly instantaneous!  This is a very nice site.

Comment: Please do not "piggyback" questions.  Ask a separate, easy to search for, discrete question so it can have an easy-to-search-for discrete set of answers.  Feel free to delete this non-answer and ask a proper question.